# Preventing Files From Being Opened

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2

I am an application developer working on a somewhat-large application suite.  We have a philosophy/best practice to never modify files directly in production, but of course it tends to happen from time to time for one reason or another.

We want a way to effectively enforce that practice by never allowing files on a certain directory (per se, a directory within the Apache2 server home) to be opened by a text editor or program from the mounted network drive, but still being able to update these files by our normal means via file transfer.

Is something like this possible?  If not, what would be the next best thing?  We are currently using Windows Server 2003.  Also interested in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

If your application runs under a certain account that is not used for a normal users to log on, you can just set permissions on the file to deny read-access.

If you application is always running under Apache or another service process, you could do:

```
icacls.exe C:\AppData\ /T /deny "NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE:(M)"
```

now no interactive user can open that file, not even an administrator. I'm not sure how well this works when accessing the file over a network share, but you maybe you can figure out the permissions that suit you.